# Can't attach entity to Database Context

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework

We are using EntityFramework on our project. I have the following code:

```
var realType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType());
    if (this.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
    {   
        this.Set(realType).Attach(entity);
    }
```

inside my Database Context class which throws an exception:

`An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`

Is why does it happens after I checked that entity was detached? How can I fix that?